# Stored procedure loop

Tags: sql, procedure

Montei essa procedure, ela faz a consulta dentro do cursor direitinho, mas quando dou select no `SPA_VALOR_ACOMODACAO`, ele retorna o 0, que foi setado antes do `loop_duracao`. Parece que não está entrando no `loop_duracao`. O que seria?

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SP_CALCULA_VALOR_ACOMODACAO;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_CALCULA_VALOR_ACOMODACAO(IN SPA_CURSO_ID INT, IN SPA_DURACAO INT, SPA_IDADE INT, IN SPA_DATA DATE, OUT SPA_VALOR_ACOMODACAO DOUBLE(20,2))
BEGIN
-- DECLARANDO VARIAVEIS INTERNAS DA PROCEDURE;
    DECLARE SPV_VALOR_NORMAL, SPV_VALOR_TEMPORADA, SPV_VALOR_PERIODO DOUBLE(20,2) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE CURSOR_FIM, LOOP_POSICAO, SPV_TEMPORADA INT DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE SPV_DATA_PROJETADA DATE DEFAULT NOT NULL;

-- DECLARANDO O CURSOR DE ACORDO COM OS CRITERIOS ATENDIDOS;
    DECLARE cursor_acomodacao CURSOR FOR SELECT valor,valor_temporada FROM `curso_navigation` WHERE curso_id = SPA_CURSO_ID AND SPA_IDADE BETWEEN idade_de AND idade_ate ORDER BY valor LIMIT 1;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET CURSOR_FIM = 1;

    OPEN cursor_acomodacao;

    loop_acomocadao: LOOP

        FETCH cursor_acomodacao INTO SPV_VALOR_NORMAL,SPV_VALOR_TEMPORADA;
        IF CURSOR_FIM = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE loop_acomocadao;
        END IF;

        SET SPA_VALOR_ACOMODACAO = 0;

        IF SPV_VALOR_TEMPORADA IS NULL THEN
            SET SPV_VALOR_TEMPORADA = SPV_VALOR_NORMAL;
        END IF;           

        SET LOOP_POSICAO = 0;
        loop_duracao: LOOP
            IF LOOP_POSICAO = SPA_DURACAO THEN
                SET CURSOR_FIM = 1;
                LEAVE loop_duracao;
            END IF;

            -- data para o dia de checkin;
            SET SPV_DATA_PROJETADA = DATE_ADD(SPA_DATA,INTERVAL LOOP_POSICAO WEEK);
            -- SETA COMO NÃO TEMPORADA
            -- TESTA DOMINGO
            SET SPV_TEMPORADA = 0;
            CALL SP_IS_TEMPORADA(SPA_CURSO_ID, FN_DATE_TO_WEEKDAY(SPV_DATA_PROJETADA, 0), NULL, SPV_TEMPORADA);
            -- Caso domingo não é TEMPORADA, testa Sabado;
            IF SPV_TEMPORADA IS NULL THEN
                CALL SP_IS_TEMPORADA(SPA_CURSO_ID, FN_DATE_TO_WEEKDAY(SPV_DATA_PROJETADA, 6), NULL, SPV_TEMPORADA);
            END IF;

            -- se nenhum é temporada, joga para o valor normal;

            IF SPV_TEMPORADA IS NULL THEN
                SET SPV_VALOR_PERIODO = SPV_VALOR_NORMAL;
            ELSE
                SET SPV_VALOR_PERIODO = SPV_VALOR_TEMPORADA;
            END IF;

            -- SOMA O VALOR TOTAL DA ACOMODACAO;

            SET SPA_VALOR_ACOMODACAO = SPA_VALOR_ACOMODACAO + SPV_VALOR_PERIODO;

            -- pula posicao;
            SET LOOP_POSICAO = LOOP_POSICAO + 1;
        END LOOP loop_duracao;
    END LOOP loop_acomocadao;
    CLOSE cursor_acomodacao;

END//
DELIMITER ;

SET @VALOR = 0;
CALL SP_CALCULA_VALOR_ACOMODACAO(1540,4,18,'2015-09-01',@VALOR);
SELECT @VALOR;
```

Answer (score 1):

Não conheço esta syntax, que linguagem SQL é essa ?

Se você executar o seguinte select:

```
select 8 + null
```

Verá que o valor será igual null, tem certeza que não está vindo nenhum null em `SPV_VALOR_PERIODO` ?

Um único valor nulo irá anular toda a conta, você pode tentar usar o COALESCE:

```
SPA_VALOR_ACOMODACAO = SPA_VALOR_ACOMODACAO + COALESCE(SPV_VALOR_PERIODO,0);
```

Também verifique o dado de saida, tem uma formatação de dados `DOUBLE(20,2)`, tenta com outro tipo para ver se não é este o problema.